# SSRS two datasets need to use field from one dataset as a parameter in second?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

The issue is that the in field that has the data is just one record in the data set pulled from a set stored proc (not touchable). 
Then using it as a parameter in the second dataset. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

1. Add parameter
2. Select parameter visibility as Hidden
3. Go to Default Values: (Screenshot of below)
4. Select "Get values from a query" (and select your first dataset and value field)
5. In Dataset 2 filter the data with your new parameter

   ```
      i.e. SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE ABC IN (@Param)
   ```

[image: Default Values Tab]

Comment: This works but in my particular case only gets the first value in my report for some reason.

Comment: Make sure you set the parameter to "Allow Multiple Values"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a subreport.

Add a subreport to the main report.
Add a parameter to the subreport.

[image]

Open the rdl of the subreport, add a paramter with the same name.

[image]
create a dataset in that RDL using your query for example

```
select * from YourTable where ENTY_KEY = (@param)
```